# Battery Charger Indicators

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

[image]

This is regarding battery level indicator. I am using MP2720 switching regulator in my circuit to charge the battery. MP2720 has only one pin for status indicator i.e.

1. If STAT pin of MP2720 is HIGH, Charged FULL
2. If STAT pin of MP2720 is LOW, Charging
3. If STAT pin of MP2720 is square wave with 1 Hz frequency, Error.

I have made a circuit with 555 timer which somehow give solution to what I want, i.e. shows correct charging and full charged indication. But when error state occurs, both circuits turns on (as the square wave is a combination of High and Low, so full charged and charging circuit turn on at High and Low level, respectively).

If it's charging (Low signal out from MP2720), then U1 turns ON (U3 disabled) and orange LED blinking. If it's full (High signal out from MP2720), then U3 turns ON (U1 disabled) and green LED turns ON.

Is there any way I can block the square wave produced by MP2720?

Please see the block diagram with circuit.

Comment: Have you added a 10k Ohm resistor as a pull-up on the STAT pin as the datasheet is asking us to do ?

Comment: If you want, you can use the MP26123. It's a battery charger as well, with the pin CHGOK  LOW if charging and HIGH if full or fault (no square wave here). Personally if I met this type of problem I would have changed the component with this one.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can block the square wave produced by MP2720?

The circuit below may help:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyfA9r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As shown in the truth table, the circuit outputs LOW when the battery is full or there's an error, and HI otherwise.

Although I put an XOR it can be anything depending on your needs. Also the STAT_X goes up to 4.4V so you may want to replace D1 with a Schottky for a lower drop so the output can go 4.8V.

Comment: One problem with the input to XOR, STAT,X. There needs to be a drain resistor of some value to bleed off the charge from C1 at an appropriate rate, otherwise the charge decay depends on leakage into the XOR.